# How to create custom expandable dialog using ControlsFX

Tags: dialog, javafx-8

I want to create the same dialog as the one created when using Dialogs.showException(), but instead of showing the stacktrace, I want to show my custom pre-formatted text. The functionality that I want is the Details button behavior.

What I want is this:

[image]

But not with the printed stacktrace.

What I have tried is to create my own Throwable, populate it with StackTraceElement objects(filled with the the text that I need) and overwrite the getStackTrace() method to return the populated array. The problem is that the stack trace is displayed from the point where the exception is thrown so the text that I need is shown at the bottom of the expanded pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`ControlsFX` is an open source project.**

The source of the Exception Dialog is available [here](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/src/e47cc550571abffff0ee56ea0f27683655cb076a/controlsfx/src/main/java/org/controlsfx/dialog/Dialogs.java?at=default#cl-532). I'm a `ControlsFX` committer, so ping me if you need more information.

Comment: I was able to create a custom dialog, which was able to handle the task that I needed it for. I will answer my own question, when I have got the time :)

Comment: all methods in this library is deprecated. is there any new way to use this lib

Comment: In short, new APIs will be part of JavaFX 8u40. They are significantly different. Latest version of ControlsFX provides access to new APIs through additional dependency even before JavaFX 8u40 is released. Old API are deprecated and will be removed as soon as ControlsFX baseline becomes 8u40.  Here is full the explanation https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/controlsfx-dev/APokeoMFnHE.